# Networking - connecting to multiple networks and forcing IP per application

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, steam

I have an edge use case:

#### Context

I would like to stream and play online games at the same time but my broadband bandwidth is quite limited.

#### Desired solution

I would like to connect my 4G Android tethered connection to use for streaming but use my broadband line for playing online games (for better latency).
Is it possible, with Ubuntu to connect to 2 networks simultaneously and bind a specific IP to a steam game/any application?

I had this use case working under Windows 10, since multiple networks seem to work out of the box and also used ForceBindIP; but recently switched to Linux.

Is my use case possible?

Thanks

Comment: I don't run two network cards in my system to test this out, but you might want to see:  https://superuser.com/questions/271915/route-the-traffic-over-specific-interface-for-a-process-in-linux

Comment: I use ethernet on my motherboard and usb for tethering. is that the same as running two network cards?

Comment: Yes, it is the same as the phone shows up as a network as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone with a similar use case: I simply connected my broadband and USB tethering to my PC and used a CLI tool called `firejail` to limit any app to any interface.

Example command:
`firejail --dns=1.1.1.1 --defaultgw=<gateway of interface> --net=<interface> --noprofile <your command>`